# Connect Gitlab (behind firewall) and Trello via Zapier

Tags: gitlab, zapier, trello

I have a self-hosted instance of Gitlab running in a local data center behind a firewall and we use Trello for all simple task/issue management.  I'd like to connect Gitlab and Trello via Zapier for an automated Trello card creation process for each new issue and/or merge request.  A recent attempt to connect the two did not work due to the firewall.

Are there any settings in Zapier I may be missing, potential work arounds, or another service beside Zapier that may solve the problem?

*We are stuck with the instance of Gitlab.*

Answer (score 0):

Requests from Zapier come from AWS. If your firewall is blocking all connections from non-whitelisted IP addresses, you've got two options if you want to use Zapier with your Gitlab instance:

1. Whitelist all AWS IP addresses (probably not what you want to do)
2. Come up with a whitelisted server that will forward requests from Zapier to Gitlab. That way you only have to whitelist a server you own.

There's more info here: https://zapier.com/help/troubleshoot/behavior/cant-access-or-use-zapier-with-other-apps

Sorry I don't have better news here!